# How do you get rid of a weird wrong colored border in the legend of a graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The histogram I generated in R has a weird cyan border around the gold marker for "Nonsmokers" in the legend. How do I get rid of this so it is just gold?

[the histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1TWf.png)

```
a = ggplot(babies,aes(x=bwt,y=..density..))

a + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1,boundary=10,data=subset(babies,smoke=='0'),aes(fill=as.factor(smoke)), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1,boundary=10,data=subset(babies,smoke=='1'),aes(fill=as.factor(smoke)), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_density(data=subset(babies,smoke == '0'),color="gold2",size = 1.25) +
  geom_density(data=subset(babies,smoke == '1'),color="cyan3",size = 1.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Mothers", values=c("gold2","cyan3"),labels=c("Nonsmokers","Smokers")) +
  labs(x = "Weights",
       y = "Density") +
  ggtitle("Weights of Babies Born to Nonsmokers") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),legend.position = c(0.2, 0.8),legend.background = element_rect(color="gray90", size=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL)))` to your plot.

Using the default `mtcars` data :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=..density..)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1, boundary=10, data=subset(mtcars,am=='0'),
                 aes(fill=as.factor(am)), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1,boundary=10,data=subset(mtcars,am=='1'),
                 aes(fill=as.factor(am)), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_density(data=subset(mtcars,am == '0'),color="gold2",size = 1.25) +
  geom_density(data=subset(mtcars,am == '1'),color="cyan3",size = 1.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Mothers", values=c("gold2","cyan3"),
                    labels=c("Nonsmokers","Smokers")) +
  labs(x = "Weights",
       y = "Density") +
  ggtitle("Weights of Babies Born to Nonsmokers") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = c(0.2, 0.8),
        legend.background = element_rect(color="gray90", size=1)) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL)))
```

[image]